# Biometrika latex template reports error when using theorem-like environments

Tags: theorems, templates, ntheorem

I need to use the [biometrika (see stylistic requirements)](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/pages/General_Instructions) tex template for writing a report. But using the theorem-like environments (even without any modification to the codes) in `styleguide.tex` gives the following error:

```
! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
\update@series@target@value #1->\def \reserved@a {
                                                   #1}\ifx \target@meta@famil...
```

The error can be caused by any theorem-like environments, for example,

```
\begin{definition}[optional argument]
This is a definition.
\end{definition}
```

I don't know much about how such enviroments in custom templates are defined. I can't even find where the codes in the error message are. What changes should I make? I am using Miktex 2.9 on Win10 if it matters.

**P.S.** The template contains several very lengthy files. I don't think copying and pasting them there is a good choice. And it's hard for me to create an mwe without causing new errors since I cannot locate the problem precisely. I'd really appreciate it if you could download the template and check why this error occurs.

Comment: as always on the site please provide a full minimal example that others can just copy and test as is. We cannot do anything with just sniplets.

Comment: @daleif I've provided a link for downloading the template. The template consists of several very lengthy files. It is hardly helpful to copy and paste all of them here. Also, since I cannot identify the problem. It is hard to choose precisely the codes to produce an mwe without causing new errors. I'd really appreciate it if you can download it.

Comment: I can confirm the problem arises compling `styleguide-SM.tex` in the biometrika latex directory.

Comment: As far as I can tell it could be compiled with TeXLIve 2018, but not 2019 or 2020

Comment: At the moment I cannot tell where the problem is. You might want to report this to Biometrika

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I thought it was only a setup problem for me. But now it seem that this could be a bug.

Comment: I know there has been some work on fonts etc in the kernel the last few years. And since `biometrika.cls` changes a lot of kernel stuff things can go wrong. Changes are they've never tested it with newer latex installations, for example `biometrika.cls` from the link is dated 2009!

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I have the same problem...

Comment: @rosa The template on overleaf works.

Comment: I can confirm that under TeX Live 2020 the problem arises compiling `styleguide-SM.tex`.

Answer (score 0):

I have same errors when compiling Biometrika2018 or Biometrika2020.
Then I change latex engine from TexLive to MikTex to fix this problem.

Comment: Please provide more details as it should not matter whether one is using miktex or texlive

Comment: I have both texlive2019 and MiKTex 2.9 installed on my computer, and set the texlive2019 as the default engine. When I use WinEdt 10.2 Editor and texlive2019 to compile the Biometrika2020 template, the above errors occur. I then just simply change texlive2019 to MiKTex 2.9, the same  Biometrika2020 template can be compiled successfully. As a primary user of Latex, I actually don't know the underlying mechanism, so I can not provide more details. Sorry for that. @daleif

Comment: You might want to add `\listfiles` to the document (before `\documentclass`) that is compiled and have a look in the log. This lists the used packages and their versions in the log. My guess is that your MikTeX is not fully up to date.

Comment: Tks! I will try it